# convert rss encoding from windows 1255 to utf 8 node js

Tags: node.js, utf-8, rss, converters, windows-1255

I am trying to parse hebrew rss like this one: 
http://rss.walla.co.il/?w=/3/0/12/@rss.e

I am using feedparser and request, and the problem is that the encoding is windows-1255 and not UTF-8

so I see the text like: ����� �������  , and not like a regular hebrew text.

I tried some converts (like iconv-lite) but I did not succeed.

This is my code:

```
function getAll(URL) {
var request = require('request');
request(URL, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var allXML = body.substring(body.indexOf('<title>') + ('<title>').length, body.indexOf('</title>'));
        var text = iconv.decode(new Buffer(allXML), 'win1255');
        console.log("text = ", text);
    }
})
```

}

and this is what it print: 
text =  ן¿½ן¿½ן¿½ן¿½ן¿½! ן¿½ן¿½ן¿½ן¿½ן¿½ - ן¿½ן¿½ן¿½ן¿½ן¿½

Answer (score 0):

You can use a module such as [`iconv`](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-iconv) or [`iconv-lite`](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite) to convert between encodings, since currently node only natively supports utf8, utf16le, latin1/binary, ascii, hex, and base64.

Answer (score 0):

I used this source: [github](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite/wiki/Use-Buffers-when-decoding)

```
function getText(URL) {
http.get(URL, function(res) {
    var chunks = [];
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
        var decodedBody = iconv.decode(Buffer.concat(chunks), 'win1255');
        console.log(decodedBody);
    });
});
```

}